# Unable to understand the notation in the chapter on manifolds

Tags: general-topology, notation, manifolds, triangulation

While self studying Topology from Wayne Patty I was unable to understand this notation on page 218 of the textbook. Subsection is Manifolds.

> Consider this statement(which is given as theorem): If X and Y are compact surface, then $\chi (X\mathbin\#Y) = \chi(X)+\chi(Y)- 2$.

Here $\chi(X)$ is Euler characteristic of $X$.

The author then writes:

> Assume $X$ and $Y$ are triangulated. Form $X\mathbin\#Y$ by removing the interior of a triangle from each and identifying the edges and vertices of the vertices of the boundaries of the triangles that have been removed.

Is there specific name (mathematical, name of the symbol is $\#$ is clear to me) for the construction $\#$ given in the theorem? How it is constructed is clear to me.

Comment: I am not sure I understood you quetion ,I believe what you are looking for is connected sum, that is $X\# Y$.

Comment: $X\# Y$ stands for the connected sum of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: The correct formula is $\chi(X) + \chi(Y)- 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In topology, the operation "#" is called *connected sum*. Its effect is to join two given manifolds together near a chosen point.